# Click an element if another element contains a specific text. Automated Test with Protractor

Tags: javascript, if-statement, protractor, automated-tests, conditional-statements

I need to check which one of 3 elements contains the text "10%" but I am not sure I am getting correctly the text of the element. When I run the code I am not getting errors but the if condition is always false(also when it should be true).

My javascript code inside the spec:

```js
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(await driver.findElement(By.css("tr:nth-child(1) .font-weight-bold-light > span"))), 30000)
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(await driver.findElement(By.css("tr:nth-child(2) .font-weight-bold-light > span"))), 30000)
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(await driver.findElement(By.css("tr:nth-child(3) .font-weight-bold-light > span"))), 30000)

var array = ["tr:nth-child(1) .font-weight-bold-light > span", "tr:nth-child(2) .font-weight-bold-light > span", "tr:nth-child(2) .font-weight-bold-light > span"];
var arrayDelete = ["tr:nth-child(1) img:nth-child(2)", "tr:nth-child(2) img:nth-child(2)", "tr:nth-child(3) img:nth-child(2)"]
for (var k = 0; k<array.length; k++){

  var allOpts = (await driver.findElement(By.css(array[k])));
  await driver.sleep(2000)

  if (allOpts == ('10%')) {
    await driver.sleep(2000)
    await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(await driver.findElement(By.css(arrayDelete[k]))), 30000)
    // 11 | click | css=.actions > img:nth-child(2) | 
    await driver.findElement(By.css((arrayDelete[k]))).click()
    // 12 | pause | 1000 | 
    await driver.sleep(5000)
    // 13 | waitForElementVisible | css=.ml-3 | 30000
    await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(await driver.findElement(By.css(".ml-3"))), 30000)
    // 14 | click | css=.ml-3 | 
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".ml-3")).click()
    // 15 | pause | 3000 | 
    await driver.sleep(10000)
    // 16 | verifyElementNotPresent | css=td:nth-child(1) | 
    {
      const elements = await driver.findElements(By.css((allOpts)))
      assert(!elements.length)
    }
    console.log(('ho cancellato l obiettivo ')+ k);
  
  } else {
    console.log(('obiettivo ') + k + (' non cancellato, in quanto il suo peso non è 10%'));
  }
}
```

I tryed all of these:

```
if (allOpts == (' 10% ')) 
if (allOpts == ('10%')) 
if (allOpts === (' 10% ')) 
if (allOpts === ('10%')) 
if (allOpts.getText() == (' 10% ')) 
if (allOpts.getText()  == ('10%')) 
if (allOpts.getText()  === (' 10% ')) 
if (allOpts.getText()  === ('10%')) 
if (allOpts.getAttribute("value") == (' 10% ')) 
if (allOpts.getAttribute("value")  == ('10%')) 
if (allOpts.getAttribute("value")  === (' 10% ')) 
if (allOpts.getAttribute("value")  === ('10%'))
```

None of these allowed to run the body of the if condition.

Here my html:

```
<td _ngcontent-lqu-c20="">
  <p _ngcontent-lqu-c20="" class="font-weight-bold-light">
    <!---->
    <span _ngcontent-lqu-c20=""> 10% </span>
  </p>
</td>
```

Comment: what happens if you console.log the text of the element?

Comment: thanks, I had to think at this before... Anyway by the console.log I saw I was not getting the text, but something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to call `getText()` to read the content on the web element

```
var allOpts = (await driver.findElement(By.css(array[k])).getText()).trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, your syntax is not typical for protractor (unless you're using some very old version). if this is the tool you'r using checkout their [documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api)

Second, in this line you're just declaring the element and not doing anything with it

```
var allOpts = (await driver.findElement(By.css(array[k])));
```

you should have extracted element's text. But using normal syntax it would look like so

```
var allOpts = await element(by.css(array[k])).getText();
```

Three, the reason this is not working

```
if (allOpts.getText() == (' 10% '))
```

is because this is promise, which you need to resolve by `.then()` or by `await`ing it. Unless you figure out this process in depth (and I mean it... in ALL details), you won't go too far with protractor

Four, when you do `.getText()` your string gets trimmed, meaning there is no spaces in the beginning and at the end (`'10%'` not `' 10% '`)

Five, when in doubt, just `console.log()` the value. It's the easiest way to debug problems

And lastly, don't use `==`, use `===` instead. For 3 years working with protractor I never had a case when I HAD to use `==`, but I did have many confusions created by [coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript) when using it

Comment: I tryed with var allOpts = await element(by.css(array[k])).getText(); but I am getting this error:  Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Comment: Okay I see why you are using this syntax. your app is not angular. `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` would solve the problem...

Comment: False, my app is Angular, if I add your command (I already tried) I get error element not found by css selector. I have solved just modifiing this:

var allOpts = (await driver.findElement(By.css(array[k])).getText()).trim()

Answer (score 0):

first you need to read the text of the element i.e. by using `getText()`.